# Nested fragment issue on addBackStack method in navigation activity, not able to get work done of backstack fragments, directly closing the app issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[image: Please check the flow]

Hi,Guys someone please help,,,,very hard trying to solve it but not able to do ... fed up with this issue,
I have a parent activity which is having navigation drawer with Home,Search,Books, Profile Fragments. added 3 tabs to Home fragment. From the first fragment of Tab I want to replace it with new fragment i.e BookDetails Frag this should be like Home-BookDetails-Cart-Login... and when I backpress it should come to respective old fragments. How can I do it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are moving from `NavigationDrawer`, use `replace`.
2. While navigating to child fragment, use `add` and put current fragment in `backstack`.

It will solve your problem

Now with this scenario, whenever user press back from Home, Search books or Profile fragment, it will close your application.

And if you are inside Book details and pressing back, it will move you to HomeFragment.

Your code for `HomeFragment` seems fine (as you have posted in comment)

But when moving from `HomeFragment` to `BookDeatailsFrag` you should use `add` instead of `replace`

```
BookDeatailsFrag fragment = new BookDeatailsFrag();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("home");
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.details, fragment, "detail").commit();
```

Comment: its just a string, you can give anything there. check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String))

Comment: suggestion : As a developer you should try everything first. If not success, atleast you will get some error and some knowledge also to solve that error :)

Comment: one issue is solved that I am able to replace current fragment to new fragment. I just need to solve backpress issue. as I followed what u have said then also its closing the app on backpress

Comment: Hey its working fine, on backpress getting blank screen other than Home Frag...is it possible to get HomeFrag inplace of blank screen?